# should new python virtualenv's be created with new linux user accounts?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm starting with Python 3, using Raspbian (from Debian), and using virtualenv.  I understand how to create/use a virtualenv to "sandbox" different Python project, HOWEVER I'm a bit unclear on whether one should be setting up a different linux user for each project (assuming that the project/virtualenv will be used to create & then run a daemon process on the linux box).

So when creating separate python environments the question I think is should I be:

1. creating a new linux user account for each deamon/acript I'm working on, so that both the python virtual environment, and the python project code area can live under directories owned by this user?
2. perhaps just create one new non-administrator account at the beginning, and then just use this account for each project/virtual environmnet
3. create everything under the initial admin user I first log with for raspbian (e.g. "pi" user) - Assume NO for this option, but putting it in for completeness.

Comment: Note that virtualenv is not sandboxing in a security sense - it's merely for isolating project dependencies.

Comment: @wim ok cool - as I started with 1 and it was a bit of a pain

Comment: @PeterGibson so option 2 should be ok then in general you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR:  1. no 2. yes 3. no

> 1. creating a new linux user account for each deamon/script I'm working on, so that both the python virtual environment, and the python project code area can live under directories owned by this user?

No. Unnecessary complexity and no real benefit to create many user accounts for this. Note that one user can be logged in multiple sessions and running multiple processes.

> 2. perhaps just create one new non-administrator account at the beginning, and then just use this account for each project/virtual environment

Yes, and use `sudo` from the non-admin account if/when you need to escalate privilege.

> 3. create everything under the initial admin user I first log with for raspbian (e.g. "pi" user) - Assume NO for this option, but putting it in for completeness.

No.  Better to create a regular user, not run everything as root.  Using a non-root administrator account would be OK, though.

Comment: So the third one is actually "yes", isn't it? My interpretation is "when I set up the box, the regular user `pi` was created for me, this is a regular account, though it's in the `sudoers` group". I see no reason to create a separate account with essentially the same privileges, and frankly don't understand the OP's obsession about creating new accounts.

Comment: Not necessarily.  I like daemons to run under the least privilege possible, and grant only the minimum needed.  Which means they are not admin accounts, and any files or directories they need access for are permissioned via groups and acls.  But it's a trade-off between security vs convenience here.

Comment: I agree that creating a separate account *might* make sense, but the way the OP phrased their question, it sounds like "I *need* to create a new account" which definitely is not true. There could be security benefits (non-guessable account name, you don't have to be in `sudoers`) but the answer I would compose would start with "yes, but" instead of "no, and".

Comment: And more generally the question really asks "should I create a new account for any virtualenv" to which the answer is a *resounding* "no, are you nuts?"

Comment: @tripleee  instead of describing how you would answer by adding comments under this answer, perhaps consider just adding your own answer.  that way it will get the proper visibility it deserves and can be vetted by the community.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback -- I have done so. I may have gone a bit over board to the point where I expect a few downvotes for making things a bit too easy for myself.

Comment: Starting point for me was here https://home-assistant.io/docs/installation/raspberry-pi/ which included doing "sudo useradd -rm homeassistant", i.e. separate to pi.   One other question here for homeassistant using this install procedure is, noting it's environment is owned by homeassistant, and it runs homeassistant as this user, THEN is it ok to be in the "pi" account when developing?  (i.e. logon as "pi" and change homeassistant config file as "pi", etc).  [i.e. noting homeassistant doesn't have a password and it's listed to sudo'ers]

Comment: There's nothing here which is strictly "not okay" but it's an unnecessary complication. Having the account's private files owned by another account may prove problematic down the line.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. From virtualenv's perspective you could do any of those.

#1 makes sense to me if you have multiple services that are publicly accessible and want to isolate them.

If you're running trusted code on an internal network, but don't want the dependencies clashing then #2 sounds reasonable.

Given that the Pi is often used for a specific purpose (not a general purpose desktop say) and the default account goes largely unused, using that account would be fine. Make sure to change the default password.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, there is no need to create a separate account just for a virtualenv.

There *can* be reasons to create a separate account, but they are distinct from, and to some extent anathema to, virtual environments. (If you have a dedicated account for a service, there is no need really to put it in a virtualenv -- you *might* want to if it has dependencies you want to be able to upgrade easily etc, but the account already provides a level of isolation similar to what a virtualenv provides *within* an account.)

Reasons to use a virtual environment:

- Make it easy to run things with different requirements under the same account.
- Make it easy to install things for yourself without any privileges.

Reasons to use a separate account:

- Fine-grained access control to privileged resources.
- Properly isolating the private resources of the account.